# How to speed up a 4-way SQLITE inner join that is slow despite covering indexes on all tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-optimization, inner-join

I have 4 tables that are taking a long time to join in SQLITE (version 3.31.1). Here's a simplified view of the 5 tables involved (the first one "Objects" is not used in the join directly):

```
Table Objects:
    Objects.Id

Table Dates:  # Each day has 2 different values of date, some tables refer to one, some to the other
    Dates.Date_cal1  # Calendar 1
    Dates.Date_cal2  # Calendar 2

Table A:
    A.Object_Id
    A.Date_c1
    A.Value_A

Table B:
    B.Object_Id
    B.Date_c1
    B.Value_B

Table C:
    C.Object_Id
    C.Date_c2
    C.Value_C
```

The (Object_id,Date) pair form a primary key for each of A/B/C. The query I am running is like this:

```
SELECT Dates.Date_cal1, A.Value_A, B.Value_B, C.Value_C
    FROM Dates
    INNER JOIN A ON A.Date_c1 = Dates.Date_cal1
    INNER JOIN B ON B.Date_c1 = Dates.Date_cal1 AND B.Object_Id = A.Object_Id
    INNER JOIN C ON C.Date_c2 = Dates.Date_cal2 AND C.Object_Id = A.Object_Id
    WHERE A.Object_Id=14
ORDER BY Dates.Date_cal1 ASC;
```

The query takes about 1-2 minutes to run. Some notes:

1. I know some of this looks silly (eg. A and B could be merged as shown here). Just assume that the real case has a reason for all this.
2. **I have covering indexes for the 4 tables:  Dates has both (Date_cal1,Date_Cal2) and (Date_cal2,Date_cal1), and A and B and C each have one ordered by (Object_Id,Date_c*,Value_*) where * is 1-or-2 and A-or-B-or-C as appropriate).**
3. In terms of size, Dates has 360 rows, A and B have 3.6 million, and C has 100 million (C is bigger because "cal2" is a finer-grained calendar - you can think of it as cal1 is once a month, cal2 is once a day).
4. The data is quite regular, meaning that each of 10k object_ids uses an approximately equal number of rows in A/B/C.

When I run EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN for the query above, I get:

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SEARCH TABLE B USING COVERING INDEX B_index (Object_Id=?)
|--SEARCH TABLE A USING PRIMARY KEY (Date_c1=? AND Object_Id=?)
|--SEARCH TABLE Dates USING PRIMARY KEY (Date_cal1=?)
|--SEARCH TABLE C USING PRIMARY KEY (Date_c2=? AND Object_Id=?)
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

Note that only the first part mentions leveraging the covering index. I'm not sure if 1 minute is reasonable, but I was hoping that full use of the covering indexes would mean that the date and object_id filtering for A/B/C would be much quicker (since for Object_Id=14, there would be a total of 360 rows in A and B, and 11k rows in C).

Thanks for any help anybody can offer!

Comment: Run an [`ANALYZE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) and see if that changes the query plan to use the covering indexes.

Comment: @Shawn, running ANALYZE did the trick. I'm surprised that it thought using searches on primary key would be good default behaviour, but just running analyze now has it showing "USING COVERING INDEX" for all 4. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting an answer to help anybody who stumbles upon this in the future. As @Shawn said in his comment above, running the ANALYZE command was key to fixing this problem for me. Even though there are covering indexes, SQLITE doesn't always use them without the ANALYZE run.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would write the query as:

```
FROM Dates JOIN
     A
     ON A.Date_c1 = Dates.Date_cal1 JOIN
     B
     ON B.Date_c1 = A.Date_c1 AND
        B.Object_Id = A.Object_Id JOIN
     C
     ON C.Date_c2 = Dates.Date_cal2 AND C.Object_Id = A.Object_Id
WHERE A.Object_Id = 14
```

I would suggest indexes on:

- `A(ObjectId, Date_c1)`
- `B(Object_Id, Date_c1)`
- `Dates(Date_cal1, Date_cal2)`
- `C(Objet_Id Date_C2)`

This should allow the `where` clause to filter the data using an index, with the rest of the joins using indexes as well.

Comment: Note my point #2 in the question where I list the indexes I already have. Don't those covering indexes give enough to let the filtering happen?

Comment: @jwcoder . . . Actually they do look correct if the columns are in that order.  I can't explain why SQLite is not using the indexes.